# Is it possible to use HttpRequest to upload files contained in a <div> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Would it be possible to upload files (contained in ) from client end to server end using Asp file uploader control. For example my div looks like:
*

```
<input type='file'/>
<div parent>
 <div child>File 1</div>
 <div child>File 2</div>
 <div child>File 3</div>
</div>
```

*
And all the files have been uploaded through `asp file uploader` control. When I post the html page `Request.Files` contains only the current page which is understandable.

What can I do to upload all these files/images when I post the page. I am not allowed to use any `ajax` control, fyi. I am also using `bootstrap` and `jquery` to use the feature on mobile devices. Is there any feature available in BootStrap similar to these which I can take advantage of. Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Html5 allows you to upload multiple files.

Comment: Yes you can, but you've to select all files at the same time. What I am trying to achieve is that user can select file 1 by 1 which will list up as a separate div and have the option to remove by a corresponding remove button. When I post the page, those files can be accessed on the server end. The reason is I am also trying to use the application on the mobile device where you can take photos using the same html5 tag just by adding accept=image/* ...